# Not getting values from response post method volley android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

i have a login successfully and now in response i want to get values from response but not getting values kindly check where i got mistake

```
 StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                semester = jObj.getJSONObject("data").optString("semester");
                regno = jObj.getJSONObject("data").optString("registration_number");
                name = jObj.getJSONObject("data").optString("name");
                mobile = jObj.getJSONObject("data").optString("mobile");
```

json response:{"status":true,"data":{"id":"1","registration_number":"10000","name":"imran","mobile":"000423001178","semester":"3"}}

Comment: What did you get instead of desire result? Some errors?

Comment: for semester and other values :'this' is not available   i got this

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `getString()` method instead of `optString`. It will give you exception if there are no field with needed name. Also, you can get "data" object only once and then use it:

```
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            JSONObject dataJson = jObj.getJSONObject("data");
            semester = dataJson.getString("semester");
            regno = dataJson.getString("registration_number");
            name = dataJson.getString("name");
            mobile = dataJson.getString("mobile");
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

in the first line of fetching response